# What cause protostar to become optically thick?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, stars

So far I get that the cloud will contain CO and will reacts with photons which cools the core but at some point the clouds becomes optically thick and allows the core to heat up. What causes the core to become optically thick? I am new to astrophysics concepts I tried looking it up.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two different effects that occur.

One of these is *pressure broadening* of the absorption lines of the gases. You see, as the gas molecules get closer together, they start to interact with each other, and the laws of quantum mechanics say that when atoms and molecules get close, their energy levels start "breeding", or multiplying, forming bands of closely-spaced energy levels that progressively grow thicker and thus provide more opportunities to absorb photons across broader regions of the EM spectrum. In a more extreme conclusion of this scenario, this is part of why that many solids are opaque - in a sense, the gases are becoming more "solid-like".

The second effect is when the gas temperature becomes suitably high that it becomes ionized, i.e. a plasma. When that happens, large quantities of mobile, separated electric charges are released within it as the atoms break down. These charges directly interact with photons. This effect is even stronger, and at the highest temperatures at the core, becomes the overriding mechanism.